# How to enable console scripts in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, setup.py

Running Python 3.6 on Redhat.

I've installed an extremely complicated project. 5 engineers worked on this for years, but they are all gone now, so I've no one to ask.

At the top level of the project:

```
setup.py
```

Inside of that:

```
# Python command line utilities will be installed in a PATH-accessible bin/
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'blueflow-connector-aims = app.connectors.aims.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-csv = app.connectors.csv.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-discovery = app.connectors.discovery.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-fingerprint = app.connectors.fingerprint.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-mock = app.connectors.mock.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-nessusimport = app.connectors.nessusimport.nessusimport:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-netflow = app.connectors.netflow.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-passwords = app.connectors.passwords.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-portscan = app.connectors.portscan.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-pulse = app.connectors.pulse.pulse:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-qualysimport = app.connectors.qualysimport.qualysimport:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-sleep = app.connectors.sleep.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-splunk = app.connectors.splunk.__main__:cli',
        'blueflow-connector-tms = app.connectors.tms.__main__:cli',
    ]
},
```

I ran:

```
pipenv shell
```

to create a shell.

If I try a console script:

```
blueflow-connector-mock
```

I get:

```
bash: blueflow-connector-mock: command not found
```

That goes to `bash` which is clearly a mistake. I also tried:

```
python3 blueflow-connector-mock
```

which gives me:

```
python3: can't open file 'blueflow-connector-mock': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I activate these console scripts, so they will actually run?

Comment: Do you need to install the package first, `python3 setup.py install`?

Comment: So I run `setup.py` as if it is a script?

Comment: Thank you, that was a good tip. I ran `python3 setup.py install` and that moved me forward. I was able to run `blueflow-connector-mock` and it was recognized as a command. However, it died with an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'